# Call cakephp controller from another script in same server

Tags: php, cakephp, file-get-contents, cakephp-2.3

I have a script on a website, let's call it my_script.php.
In that same server, I have a **cakephp 2.3** application with a specific controller/action that runs certain background tasks. That function can be called via URL like http://example.com/controller/action/param1

Now I need to make it so every time `my_script.php` is loaded, it calls the cakephp function I mention above sending a parameter.

I can do that easily using

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/controller/action/param1');
```

However, since both scripts are located in the same server, it seems to me that it's unnecessary having to make DNS requests, or even just use the IP of the server, to call that cakephp function.

Is there any way to make that call without using a public URL (and passing a parameter)? Just using file paths I mean. I've tried:

```
$result = file_get_contents('/controller/action/param1');

$result = file_get_contents('/path/to/app/webroot/index.php/controller/action/param1');

$result = file_get_contents('/path/to/app/webroot/index.php?controller=controller&action=action&param1=param1');
```

But none of those seemed to work. Is it possible or should I just use the full URL? Or maybe not using `file_get_contents()` but something else?

Comment: Did you know that you can use Cake console scripts for background tasks? Then you can make call using model methods without using controller action.

Comment: `with a specific controller/action that runs certain background tasks` Please see [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940393/cakephp-shell-command-cant-bypass-beforefilter/32945843#32945843)- What you're currently trying to do is not a good idea/design.